# Как добавить Recyclerview в разметку к остальным элементам?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Добрый день.
У меня есть XML-разметка:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Мне надо чтобы у меня в активити отображались три радиобаттона и снизу всю остальную часть занимал Recyclerview. Но, при таком добавлении студии что-то не нравится: пропадает дерево добавленных компонентов (Component tree пустым становится).

Есть какие-нибудь альтернативы совместной работы Recyclerview с другими вьюшками на одном макете?

Comment: Как именно и куда вы добавляете `RecyclerView`. Никаких проблем с совместной работой этого виджета с другими вьюшками в одном макете обычно не наблюдается.

Comment: У вас просто в preview оно не работает - на девайсах работать будет - просто не пользуйтесь preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если надо что бы RadioGroup была постоянно видна то

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <тут RadioGroup>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/post_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weigth="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Если надо что бы RadioGroup была элементом списка, то придется добавлять её через адаптер.

Comment: Первый вариант. Ошибок никаких не возникает, но пропадает дерево компонентов. Если убрать Recyclerview - оно возвращается. По какой причине - не могу понять.

Comment: Я поправил код разметки, должно сработать. Забейте на визуальный редактор разметки - он дно.

Comment: Вес (weigth) для списка указывать в данном случае нет никакой необходимости. Верхний виджет имеет высоту `wrap_content` и "заберет" себе только нужную ему высоту. Указание высоты `match_parent` для следующего виджета отдаст ему все оставшееся в контейнере пространство. Вычисление веса в данной разметке будет пустой тратой ресурсов, а результат одинаков и без указания веса. Способ с весом применяется, когда нужно наоборот, верхнему виджету отдать все пространство за исключением места снизу для каких то кнопок и тп.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы в предпросмотре отображались элементы RecyclerView, можно использовать команду
`tools:listitem`. Вот рабочий код из моего проекта:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:background="@color/background"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/background_orange"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messages_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_message_right"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```